# How do I create list<file, file.creationTime> from a List<file>?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-10.0

Hi I have a list of files. I need to make a dictionary kind of data structure in the format <file, DateTime>, and then sort it based on DateTime and remove latest 'n' entries. I did this,

```
filesDictionary = files.ToDictionary(x => x, x => x.CreationTime);
```

But since Dictionaries are unordered, I thought it is safe to use list of key,value pair in C#,But not sure how to actually write the code similar to above.

I considered sortedLists.But they sort based on Key, I want to sort based on value.

(Also please advise if there are any better efficient option to do this.)

Answer (score 3):

It would be significantly easier to invert your order of operations.

1. Order the files by their creation date descending so that the newest files are on top.
2. Skip the first n files you don't want.
3. Make it into a Dictionary.

```
var fileDictionary = files.OrderByDescending(x => x.CreationDate)
      .Skip(n)
      .ToDictionary(x => x, x => x.CreationTime)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a dictionary or something else for it. You can sort your collection and skip the first 10 times and take the rest.

```cs
// if you want first 10 items
var latest10Items = files.OrderByDescending(r=> r.CreationTime).Take(10).ToList();

// if you want the items except first 10
var rest = files.OrderByDescending(r=> r.CreationTime).Skip(10).ToArray();

// if you want the items except first 10 in a dictionary format
var rest = files.OrderByDescending(r=> r.CreationTime).Skip(10).ToDictionary(r=> r.CreationTime);
```

Comment: I'm not sure OP wants to actually remove the files. It sounds like they might want a dictionary that doesn't include the latest N entries (note they say remove entries, not remove files).

Comment: Also `File.Delete` doesn't take a `FileInfo` (`FileInfo` has its own `Delete` method).

Comment: Yes, I need to keep the <key,value> format.

Comment: @Soumya you can create your dictionary after the `Skip` method. If you do so the rest of the items will be out of order. If you want to use a dictionary and keep the sort order you may want to look in to `SortedDictionary` class

Answer (score 1):

You can use `KeyValuePair` with

```
filesDictionary = files
   .Select(x=> new KeyValuePair<string, DateTime>()
      {
        Key = x,
        Value = x.CreationTime
      })
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Value)
    .Skip(n);
```

Comment: What is the relevance of `public class KeyValue<TKey, TValue>`?

Comment: As I understood, OP wanted a structure similar to Dictionary, which is basically a set of  Key Value pairs.

Comment: Yeah, but you created a `KeyValue` class and you're not using it, you're using the built-in `KeyValuePair` struct.

Comment: My bad, I mixed up some stuff while searching the old codebase. Edited.